# Plane shifter Hole of Oblivion (patent pending)

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation, falling, portals

A Warlock who takes the Planeshifter paragon path  can use an ability at level 12 called Quick Portal. At 15, that same Warlock could learn Create Teleportation Circle and say create a teleportation circle that was attached to a 50ft drop.... Into a lake of acid... With flesh eating piraña... You see where I am going with this.

Seeing as the portal could come out anywhere and only lasts for one round, would it be a legal maneuver to say create said portal, spend and action point, then use something like Lash of the Long Night to send an enemy flying through said portal to their unavoidable fate?

Would said target get a saving throw since it would be assumed they would be falling?

Answer (score 6):

*Rules Compendium* page 213;

> ## Teleportation
>
> **Destination Space:** If arriving in the destination space would cause the target to fall or if that space is hindering terrain, the target can immediately make a saving throw. On a save, the teleportation is negated. Otherwise, the target arrives in the destination space.

So yes you can attempt to push them into a teleportation portal if it's over a pit or something however they do get a saving throw and if they succeed they don't go through the portal but remain in a square adjacent to the portal (the last square they entered before they would have gone through).
That is, however, only if the portal ends in a drop.

As the others have mentioned, there are perhaps more viable destinations which wouldn't require a saving throw, such as a sealed off room with no exit, or a random floating bit of terrain (if there is such a thing in your campaign) with no way off but to jump.
The one problem I see with that though is since *Quick Portal* lasts until the end of you **next** turn, unless the creature is immobilised, restrained, or some such condition, they are just going to walk right back through the portal, unless you can seal if off before they get a turn or have a trap that activates on the other side when the creature is teleported there, thus putting the portal out of reach.

Comment: This means that the destination shouldn't be a fall nor hindering terrain. However, other destination possibilities are still viable. For example, an isolated cage buried deep underground wouldn't require a saving throw; nor would a dungeon room with a trigger that drops a room-sized boulder when anybody is teleported there.

Comment: Being a Fey Warlock, that isn't so tall of an order. We have lots of moves that immobilize or worse. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Teleportation circles are supposed to be on the ground

The quick portal feature says:

> Effect: You create a portal in an unoccupied square within
> range that lasts until the end of your next turn. The portal
> **leads to a permanent teleportation circle** on your current plane.

Permanent teleportation circles are described on p. 307 PHB:

> Most major temples, important wizards’ guilds, and large cities have permanent teleportation circles, each of which has a unique set of magic sigils **etched or inlaid into the ground**.

While you might argue that you could etch a circle of sigils around a central hole, and only the sigils need to be etched into "the ground", I think it is pretty clear that the intention is that "the ground" refers to the area that the circle is etched into, so that it provides a landing space for the teleported creatures. So it is not clear how the teleportation portal would even be "attached to a 50 feet drop", and you cannot use quick portal to teleport someone into mid-air, as you could with, for example *Dimension Door*.

Answer (score -3):

I think this would need a house rule as while the rules clearly state they will get a saving throw if they are to be teleported somewhere they will be falling or hindering terrain. This makes sense until you start thinking about it a little harder.

Example situation using op's ideas:

There are two warlocks the first uses op's idea and creates a teleportation circle to a pool of acid. The other creates one to an empty and unassuming cave that has no natural way out: it is essentially a stone prison with no way in or out besides the circle.
Does it really make sense for an enemy (let's say a high level orc warrior) to be thrown at the first one and get a saving throw, and have a chance to not get thrown into certain death, while he wouldn't get a saving throw being thrown into the second, which will ensure he dies eventually without a way out? (And even if it doesn't die, because of being something like undead, it's stuck there and dealt with.)

While there are some creatures that would easily get out of this second trap, many humanoids cannot. From the warlock's standpoint, both methods are about the same effectiveness since both of the orcs are now somewhere else and no longer have to be dealt with.

Also from the orc's perspective of how would this work, would it be able to see as it is being thrown through the air where that portal is going and if its not safe he has a chance of not being forced through, but if it is safe its still not somewhere that orc would want to go, so does it make sense for the orc not to get a saving throw in this situation.

I guess my point is that the rule they are using is inconsistent in this case. Either allow a saving throw no matter where the teleportation goes, or don't allow one at all.